How do I test errors in a hook that suspends before it throws?
Using testing-library/react, I can use a combination of renderHook, expect and toThrowError to check that the hook throws an error under certain conditions:
it("throws an error", async () => {
  expect(
    () => renderHook(() => usePizza(), { wrapper })
  ).toThrowError("oops");
}); // works


Normally, this works as advertised. But my hook suspends before it throws the error:
export const usePizzaWithSuspense = (clumsy) => {
  const pizza = use(bakedPizza); // <- suspends here
  if (clumsy) {
    throw new Error("oops I dropped it");
  }
  return `mmm: ${pizza}`;
};

const bakedPizza = new Promise((resolve) =>
  setTimeout(() => resolve("delicious pizza"), 100)
);


... and this pattern no longer seems to work.
it("throws an error", async () => {
  expect(
    () => renderHook(() => usePizzaWithSuspense(true), { wrapper })
  ).toThrowError("oops");
}); // doesn't work


The error is never thrown (even though in the non-error case the hook renders successfully).
How can I test an error in a hook that is thrown after the hook suspends?
See CodeSandbox example.

Just FYI, your "usePizzaWithSuspense" - "tastes delicious" test case incorrectly uses the usePizzaWithUseEffect hook.

Thanks @DrewReese - fixed. (That doesn't change anything about the question; the suspense versions still fails as shown.)

Were you able to resolve this @Sasgorilla?
